# How to host multiple dockerized websites (ngnix) in one ip address?

Tags: angularjs, api, docker, haproxy

Here is my scenario:
1. I have an aws ec2 machine (coreOs)
2. I have hosted multiple APIs in that - all in docker containers 
3. I have HA proxy listening to another port that listens to certain port (say 999) and load balances multiple APIs. Works perfectly ...
4. I have another ngnix container which hosts my angular site. This obviously listens to port 80. Assume it's mapped to http://pagladasu.com

What I want is create http://one.pagladasu.com and http://two.pagladasu.com and so forth. And want each pointing to different angular application in the docker containers.

Issue is - both need to listen to port 80 - so how to accomplish tha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a container that listens on port 80 and runs Nginx. Configure Nginx with virtual hosts for each of your subdomains (`one.pagladasu.com`, `two.pagladasu.com`), using `proxy_pass` to send the connections to upstream angular containers. Something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name one.pagladasu.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://one-pagladasu-com;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name two.pagladasu.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://two-pagladasu-com;
    }
}
```

Link this Nginx container to the two angular containers. Docker will modify `/etc/hosts` for you so that you may refer to them by name. In this case I've assumed they are named like `one-pagladasu-com` but of course it can be anything.

Now the flow is Requests => Nginx virtual hosts container => Angular container => HAProxy => APIs.

Comment: Angular containers will also have ngnix right ?
In other words - I create containers for each angular app just like the same way we would have done otherwise as separate hosted apps. 
However on top we create virtual host with another ngnix instance which will control these --- right?

Comment: Yes, you put another Nginx container in front with the virtual hosts, and those proxy incoming connections to the angular containers. Or if you want, keep both angular sites in the same container under different paths (`/mysite1` and `/mysite2`) and use nginx to route to them based on host name.